# Flyway keeps printing annoying messages for every single migration on Sybase ASE

Tags: flyway

Database: jdbc:jtds:sybase://test:4102/test (ASE 15.70)

Validated 2 migrations (execution time 00:00.024s)
**Sybase does not support setting the schema for the current session. Default schema NOT changed to dbo**
Current version of schema dbo: 10.1.001 Schema dbo is up to date. No migration necessary.
**Sybase does not support setting the schema for the current session. Default schema NOT changed to dbo**

My flyway.config is straightforward:

```
flyway.encoding=UTF-8
flyway.placeholderReplacement=true
flyway.validateOnMigrate=true
flyway.cleanOnValidationError=false
flyway.baselineDescription=Baseline
flyway.baselineOnMigrate=true
flyway.outOfOrder=false
```

How can I get rid of these messages?